# Humanly Read Tab Delimited TXT Files

Tags: csv, human-readable

Normally I work with Comma Delimited CSV files, and whenever I need to scan over the data, I just open it up in Excel, and there it is, organised neatly into columns.

However, on this occasion I have been given a tab delimited text file. If I open it up in MS Notepad, because the values and headings are all variable and different widths, the data is very disjointed. Easy for a computer to read. Not easy for me to read!

So far I have tried Notepad, Excel and Sublime Text.

**Is there a program that will display a tab delimited text file, organised into humanly readable columns?**

Thanks

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Answer (score 0):

I hope notepad++ can help you here.

Please try:
http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Notepad++ didn't work, unfortunately. After doing some reading, it seems there might be some long workarounds with plugins and such, but effort I don't really want to go into. I have managed to get it working in Excel though, just requires a few tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it just required a few tweaks in Excel for it to format correctly.

I first changed the file extension from `.txt` to `.csv` and followed this guide:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-convert-delimited-text-files-into-excel-spreadsheets/

**In short:**

1. Open the file in MS Excel.
2. Highlight the first column (which is where all your data will be)
3. Select the *Data* tab in the File menu.
4. Select *Text to Columns* and follow the Wizard